# Encrypting values of a json file using python

Tags: python, encryption

There are many tutorials out there on how to encrypt a string or file using e.g. AES. However I want to just encrypt the values (not the keys) of a json file so I will still be able to parse the encrypted json file.
A solution that came to my mind is to use a loop and encrypt all the values before saving the json file. However I am not sure whether this approach is secure. I don't know exactly how aes works but when I think of symmetric encryption it seems logical to me that encrypting many small peaces would lead to always using just the beginning of the passphrase which makes it less secure. Are these concerns unjustified? Is there any solution/library for what I want to do?
Sorry for my bad english and thank you for your help!

Comment: Smaller pieces are normally [padded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) to the size of an AES block, so that should not be a concern if implemented correct. However, when implementing any kind of cryptography there are quite a few other things that can go wrong (e.g. IVs and [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation)), so you'd better check that deeper.